# Generalization of the Kobayashi-Hitchin correspondence to almost-complex manifolds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $(X, \omega)$ be a compact Kahler manifold of dimension $n$. Then the so-called Kobayashi-Hitchin correspondence in this case says that

**Theorem**
Let $E\rightarrow (X, \omega)$ be a holomorphic vector bundle, then $E$ admits an Hermite-Einstein metric if and only if it is $\mu$-polystable and each piece of the direct sum is a $\mu$-stable holomorphic vector bundle of the same slope and Hermite-Einstein constant of $E$.

Let me be more precise. Let $h$ be an hermitian metric and $\nabla$ the Chern connection associated with $h$ and the holomorphic structure on $E$, then we say that $E$ (or $h$) is Hermite-Einstein if $\sqrt{-1}\Lambda_\omega F_\nabla=\lambda Id_E$, where $\lambda$ is a constant determined by the topology of $X$ (once $\omega$ is fixed) and $E$, $F_\nabla$ is the curvature $2$-form with valued in $End(E)$ of the Chern-connection $\nabla$ and $\Lambda_\omega$ is the contraction with $\omega$.

Moreover $E$ is $\mu$-polystable if it is holomorphically isomorphic to $(E_1,h_1)\oplus\dots\oplus(E_k,h_k)$ and each $E_i$ is a $\mu$-stable holomorphic vector bundle with $\mu(E_i)=\mu(E)$

*I know that this correspondence has been generalized also when the base space is a complex manifold by Li and Yau. So at this point I was wondering if there is a similar generalization when the base space is no longer a complex manifold but only an almost-complex manifold $(X,J)$, say.*

Notice that if we know that $X$ is only almost-complex we can no longer consider holomorphic vector bundles over it (since the projection has to be holomorphic..but we don't know if there is a complex structure on $X$). So at this point I pose my question:

**Question**

> Is there an analogous correspondence in the case the base space is a compact (for simplicity) almost-complex manifold $(X, J)$? I mean, I'm asking if there is some sort of generalization of "pseudo-holomorphic" vector bundles on $(X,J)$ and stability for which we can obtain a similar correspondence.

Any help/comment/correction and remark is appreciated.

Comment: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1214458107